# browsing broken

Tags: browser, connection-issues

Sometimes when I am trying to use my phone after work, the browser gets stuck and nothing seems to fix it.  I have tried tweaking 4g and wifi settings, but even after toggling them the browser is still not working.  I know I can hard-reset my phone, but I don't like having to wait for the reboot.  Is there anything else I can do besides a reset?

Comment: Changing browser helps?
Try dolphin or opera or anything...

Comment: Any app that requires network connectivity seems to be broken... gmail, maps, firefox

Comment: Is it possible that you have different ip settings to connect to internet @home and @work?
I've solved this using a wonderful free app called static ip

Comment: How does static ip help me?  It looks like it is for switching between a home network with static addresses and the carrier 3g or 4g connection with dhcp

Comment: @goose1 Can you please describe how the browser is "stuck" and what exactly happens to the other apps?  Do they stop responding?  Is it just that they can't connect?

Comment: When the browser is stuck, I cannot receive email and google maps is also broken.

Comment: @goose1: if you're not receiving email and maps as well, this is highly unlikely to be a browser problem, you have problem with your internet connection, what internet connection are you using? 3G or Wifi or something else?

Comment: I don't use 4g.  Usually 3g, but it can happen with wifi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a problem like this with my Sprint EVO Shift, except toggling 3G would usually get things to work.  While I was debugging I found a free app called [reset connections](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dazbradbury.restartConnections&feature=search_result) that was at least faster than toggling data services off and on again.  I don't know if that will solve your problem, but it's something to try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Galaxy S and home WiFi, but it got fixed by disabling and enabling WiFi to register it again to my router. Maybe you could try to go to flight mode and then back to normal mode to re-register with your network?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried force closing? `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Browser > Force Close`?

Comment: I can try that but I have doubts about its effectiveness.  When the browser is stuck, I cannot receive email and google maps is also broken.